# OAuth "nested" params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

The problem with the Ruby library OAuth (0.4.5) when I use a "nested" params in the query.

Example:

That does not work that request

```
current_user.myapp.client.post('/api/weights', {"weight[value]"=> 65})
```

I got

```
---! Ruby / object: Net:: HTTPUnauthorized
body:! str
   str: Invalid OAuth Request
   "@ _rails_html_safe": false
body_exist: true
code: "401"
```

And this is working

```
current_user.myapp.client.post('/api/weights', {:weight => {:value => 65})
```

But the params do not come correct:

```
Parameters: {"weight" => "value65"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this bug https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby/pull/35